# Get content from meta in external website

Tags: python, django

I need to extract the meta description of an external website. I've already searched and maybe the simple answer is already out there, but I wasn't able to apply it to my code.

Currently, I can get its title doing the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import parse

url = "https://technofall.com/how-to-report-traffic-violation-pay-vehicle-fines-e-challan/"
page = urlopen(URL)
p = parse(page)
print (p.find(".//title").text)
```

I am getting title from here

However, the description is a bit trickier. It can come in the form of:

```
<meta name="og:description" content="blabla"
<meta property="og:description" content="blabla"
<meta name="description" content="blabla"
```

So what I want is to extract the first one of these that appears inside the Html.

Comment: Did you figure out something about this ?